# Sharing .env file between apps in development

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm trying to dockerize my project, and I've come up with the following file structure:

```
project/
├── app1/
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── venv/
├── app2/
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── venv/
├── .env
└── docker-compose.yml
```

In each `main.py`, I would like to use pydantic's `BaseSettings` to read env vars from `.env` file.

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Config(BaseSettings):
    VAR: str

    class Config:
        env_file = "???"

config = Config()
```

The question is: how do I use my single `.env` file each `main.py` file? Or have I already used some antipatterns and this isn't possible with the current file structure?

*PS. I understand that it has nothing to do with docker, it's there for context.*

Comment: I'd think about putting `.env` into it's own package that's installed into each app's venv.

Comment: @Woodford yeah, but in my case, different apps share some variables, so if I wanted to update one, I would have to update it in each `.env` file...

Comment: Your settings would come from the shared package, not explicitly using the `env_file` mechanism. There are other ways to establish base settings than a `.env` file.

Comment: @Woodford how would that package look like and how do I integrate it with Docker?